# Minimum AMP HTML example

Tags: html, amp-html

The AMP project page https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml identifies this as the minimum valid page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="canonical" href="hello-world.html" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>Hello World!</body>
</html>
```

This looks like a lot, especially the CSS. Is this REALLY the minimum?

Comment: You can remove that blizzard sign, so no, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the simplest AMP page. The provided CSS in the `amp-boilerplate` is something that you must not change and is explained by Malte Ubi as a hack that creates this illusion of instantaneous page loading.